# Slim Application Error > Mustache

Tags: php, mustache, slim

**Any ideas on how to fix this?**

Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Details

Type: Mustache_Exception_RuntimeException
Message: Failed to create cache directory "storage".
File: /var/www/html/Site/vendor/mustache/mustache/src/Mustache/Engine.php
Line: 705
Trace

```
#0 /var/www/html/Site/vendor/mustache/mustache/src/Mustache/Engine.php(591): Mustache_Engine->writeCacheFile('storage/__Musta...', 'loadSource('...')
#2 /var/www/html/Site/index.php(29): Mustache_Engine->loadTemplate('index.html')
#3 /var/www/html/Site/index.php(41): renderTemplate('index.html')
#4 /var/www/html/Site/index.php(56): loadPage('index')
#5 [internal function]: {closure}()
#6 /var/www/html/Site/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(441): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#7 /var/www/html/Site/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php(1314): Slim\Route->dispatch()
#8 /var/www/html/Site/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/Flash.php(85): Slim\Slim->call()
#9 /var/www/html/Site/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/MethodOverride.php(92): Slim\Middleware\Flash->call()
#10 /var/www/html/Site/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/PrettyExceptions.php(67): Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride->call()
#11 /var/www/html/Site/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php(1261): Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions->call()
#12 /var/www/html/Site/index.php(73): Slim\Slim->run()
#13 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mustache failed to create the directory because the web server (Apache) does not have the current permissions.

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/
```

Applying the above command to the right directory fixed the issue and all the files generated as expected once slim was allowed to create the files.

Answer (score 2):

This is just what it says on the tin. In order to cache compiled templates, Mustache needs to be able to write to the cache directory. If PHP (or the web server process it's running under) can't write to the cache directory, you should create the directory yourself and `chown` and `chmod` so that it can.

Comment: chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/
Fixed the issue and loads Mustache. Got some more issues to fix but thanks for the help. One step forward :)